# Code highlighting bug

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, safari

I'm using Safari on my iPad to browse Stack Overflow.

Everything is completely fine, but sometimes I get a problem where only half of the code is highlighted like this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

I'm not sure if it is my browser’s problem or is it a bug from SO.

Note: This does not happen only on one post, but it happens to any post which have code blocks in it.

Network info(if it helps): I’m using a home Wi-fi router (ISP: First media)

[image]

Comment: Can you give link to the post, so we can compare/reproduce?

Comment: Here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68599967/adding-redirect-after-the-alert

Comment: @VLAZ Unfortunately It doesnt happen only one that one specific post, it happens on any post that has code blocks in it

Comment: Can you check in developer tools if the markup is similar to what I have in chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUU6Q.png

Comment: I don't know CSS but it seems this question should be helpful for anyone that wants to debug: [iPad Safari scrolling causes HTML elements to disappear and reappear with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807620/ipad-safari-scrolling-causes-html-elements-to-disappear-and-reappear-with-a-dela)

Comment: Can you add some information about the ***network connection*** (incl. the "weakest link"), e.g. [3G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3G), [4G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4G), [Wi-Fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi), (home) routers, [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider), country/continent, and *actual* bandwidth/latency/reliability? In other words, what is the (approximate) path from your device to the Stack Overflow server? Please respond by [changing your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/410494/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Update:").

Comment: The highlighting colors stop in the middle of letters. That indicates it's either a browser issue or that there's some element overlaying the code which is applying a transform. While it would be good to look for stray elements in the page causing this (perhaps a userscript or extension?), this feels more like a browser issue. OTOH, that doesn't mean there isn't something SO can do differently which works around the browser issue (assuming that's what it is).

Comment: on an off note is that the highlighting stops not only in the middle of the letters, but the cutoff happens on a straight vertical line for each and every line of text.

Comment: Safari is the new IE. Only updated with the OS, the only browsing engine available on the OS, pretty much ignored by the company that makes it.

Comment: @OlegValter  yeah iit only highlights the codes that are visible at the viewport when loaded, so when i scroll to the side, the codes on the overflow isnt highlighted which is why the cutoff happens on a vertical line at every line, seems like a browser issue

Comment: @rene i dont think safari on ipad has dev tools like that, im still trying to find a way to access the dev tools

Comment: @PeterMortensen i have edited my questions with the network information, Not sure if it will help but i hope so

Comment: @kaiido, yes it does solve my problem. Turns out that it is a browser issue, thank you so much